# 403 Forbidden error on my site with certain url pattern

Tags: html, url, server

When I try to navigate to my site by typing the url as "address.com" I get the 403 forbidden error. But when I type "www.address.com" or "address.com/" the site loads fine. Anyone know why this is or what I can do to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your server config, Anonymising where possible. What have you tried to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your server config. For nginx, for example, it can be located in one of the paths

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf or /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf or /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.
```

Make sure that the server_name line in the server block indicates the domain without WWW.
For example:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name example.com;
...
}
```

You can also configure a redirect from www to the domain without www.
For example:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.example.com;
return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

After the changes, you need to restart nginx.

sudo service restart nginx 
or
sudo nginx -s reload

If you use CMS like WordPress, you need to check the host settings in the admin panel (whether it is written without www) and then look for problems in .htacess, which is usually located in the root directory of a site. The search should look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^www].*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If none of this helps, you should also check the dns entries.